# How to efficiently flatten a dictionary of Sorted dictionaries to numpy.arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, data-structures, flatten

I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way to flatten my data. See below example of the data structure being flattened:

```
 {t: SortedDict(
    {0: {'t': 5, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    1: {'t': 2, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    2: {'t': 4, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    3: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    4: {'t': 4, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    5: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    6: {'t': 3, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    7: {'t': 2, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    8: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}, 
    9: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'1': ['data']}]}
    }),t:SortedDict(
    {
    27: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'5': ['data','data']}]}, 
    28: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'5': ['data','data','data','data']}]}, 
    29: {'t': 2, 'ids': [{'5': ['data','data']}]}, 
    30: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'5': ['data']}]}, 
    31: {'t': 2, 'ids': [{'5': ['data','data','data','data']}]}, 
    32: {'t': 1, 'ids': [{'5': ['data']}]}
    })}
```

Note: SortedDict comes from Sorted Containers library which is an Apache2 licensed Python sorted collections.

I have evaluated several other stackoverflow posts that do something similar with list comprehension or with a lambda function. Ultimately, I wrote a method that flattens the dictionary in to three list; however, I’m not sure if this approach is the optimal one. The method is as follows:

```
def flatten(self, d,calculation_dict):
    l_key       = [] # Stores linearized keys
    l_results   = [] # Stores linearized values after calculation
    index       = [] # Stores the start of each individual sub-array
    i = 0
    for val in d.values():
            index.append(i)
            for key, t in val.t.items():
                #Add calculation in here since I am Iterating over every element
                l_results.append(t["t"] *  calculation_dict[key]) 
                l_key.append(key)
                i += 1
    h_index = numpy.array(index, dtype=numpy.int32)
    h_l_results = numpy.array(l_results,dtype=numpy.float)
    l_key = numpy.array(l_key, dtype=numpy.int32)
    index.append(i) 
    return (l_key,l_results,index)
    
    #Need output to be numpy.array
    l_key       = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
    l_results   = [5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1,0]
    index       = [0, 10]
```

In my application speed is extremely important. So, any feedback or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I need my final results in a numpy array. Not sure if that changes anything.

Edit: Thanks to Glauco suggestion I modified the flattened Method as follows:

```
def flatten_numpy(self, d,calculation_dict):
        l_results   = numpy.empty(self.size,dtype=numpy.float)
        l_key       = numpy.empty(self.size, dtype=numpy.int32)
        index       = []
        i = 0
        for val in d.values():
                index.append(i)
                for key, t in val.t.items():
                    l_results[i] = (tf["tf"] *  idf[term]) 
                    l_key[i] = term
                    i += 1
        index.append(i) 
        h_index = numpy.array(index, dtype=numpy.int32)
        return (l_key,l_results,index)
```

It turns out that earlier in the Algorithm, I already had to access the size of each sub dictionary. Taking advantage of this I started accumulating this value size variable, and after testing the new approach it is slightly faster. Test results are below:

```
#Each Test was executed on the different data and ran 1000 times
Test#1 | Flatten        6.422301292419434   | Flatten_numpy     4.761376142501831
Test#2 | Flatten        5.212526082992554   | Flatten_numpy     4.901215553283691
Test#3 | Flatten        5.2060017585754395  | Flatten_numpy     5.266955852508545
Test#4 | Flatten        6.079436302185059   | Flatten_numpy     4.803238153457642
Test#5 | Flatten        5.059106349945068   | Flatten_numpy     4.565468788146973
```

Comment: A `SortedDict` is not a native Python data type, so you need to include its definition in your question, too.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. SortedDict comes from Sorted Containers library which is an Apache2 licensed Python sorted collections. For all intents and purpose, we can consider the SortedDict to be a native Python dictionary as it supports all the same behavior.
The desired output of the flatten method is given in the example.

Comment: Um, what does `val.t.` do? What is `calculation_dict`?

Comment: Anyway, what is wrong with your approach? What is inefficient about it?

Comment: Good catch. Basically, my original data structure is a dictionary of dictionaries of sorted dictionaries. And I’m only flattening one particular key in that structure which in this scenario is called “t”. “t” obviously is not the real name, I had to rename because of personal data. 

'calculation_dict' is a dictionary with values, that map to then same key that need to get multiplied together.

Comment: One of the researchers, in my lab, flippantly told me, I should use list comprehension or a lambda function as it would be more efficient. But didn’t explain why. And when I was reviewing other stack overflow post about flattening a list of list or a dictionary of dictionaries quite a few of them use that approach. Basically, it’s a sanity check, since my project is all about speeding up an existing algorithm; so, efficiency is crucial. And, in this scenario I can't think of a faster way of accomplishing what I want to do. So, I decided to reach out to the hive mind.

Comment: @Crux that person doesn't know what they are talking about. List comprehensions and "lambdas" are not for performance, thy are for style/readability. Particularly `lamdba` is silly, at least list comprehensions do some minor optimizations, but generally marginal.

Comment: You can pretty much discount the opinion of anyone who says "you should use a lambda function because it would be more efficient"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! I really couldn't see what he was talking about that's the primary reason I posted. I hate asking that guy any questions. On a different note, forgot to mention that I need my final results in a numpy array. Not sure if that changes anything. I added the change to the code above. The reason it needs to be in a numpy array is that i am using pybind11 to access this data in C for GPU stuff.

Comment: Dict access is one by one, so there isn't alot you can do speed it up, except by using `keys`, `items` and `values` to get lists. Lists to arrays is straight forward. Your inner most dicts are small, 1 or 2 keys, so you can't do much to speed them up.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is algorithmically right it's O(n+m) it's linear, no other way.
If you know haom many dict will arrives from cluster, so it's more convenient to create empty numpy data structures and fill it at run time, avoiding list appends.

Finally, the **t** compuatation:

> l_results.append(t["t"] *  calculation_dict[key])

can be done quickly using arrays, at the bottom of collection phase

Comment: 2) There are only two ways, that I can think of, to know the size: one would be to have a persistent variable that tracks the total number keys or ‘t-values’ as they are added to the system; the other approach, would be to pre-scan through the data before flattening it, which means accumulating the len() of each sub dictionary. I’m not sure if performing either of these approaches would give any performance gains versus merging a list into a numpy array. But maybe you know better?

Comment: 3) Regarding the t compuatation, I’m not sure what you’re referring to when you say it can be more efficiently done at the bottom of the collection phase. The reason I added it to this portion is because every t-value and key-value must be iterated/retrieved in order to be added to the flatten array. Additionally trying to perform this calculation on the flatten, numpy array would be costly due to pointer chasing between keys and values stored in two different arrays. Maybe you meant something different so a clarification or example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) I do agree that the asymptotic complexity is O(n+m) where n ranges between 1 and 1000 and where m ranges between 1 and 1M.